# why hidden box using in php post method in form

Tags: php, forms

Hi I am in New In Php.

I am asking why we are using hidden text box and given value =1.

```
<input type="text" name="form_submitted" value="1"/> 

<html> 

<head>

<title>Registration Form</title> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 

</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (isset($_POST['form_submitted'])): ?> 

<?php if (!isset($_POST['agree'])): ?> 

<p>You have not accepted our terms of service</p> 

<?php else: ?> 

<h2>Thank You <?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?></h2> 

<p>You have been registered as <?php echo $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname']; ?>  </p>

<p> Go <a href="sample.php" >back</a> to the form</p> 

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php else: ?> 

<h2>Registration Form</h2> 

<form action="sample.php" method="POST">

First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br> 

Agree to Terms of Service: <input type="checkbox" name="agree"> <br> 

**<input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1"/>** 

<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form> 

<?php endif; ?> 

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Try to edit the question so that we know exactly what it is you need help with

Comment: No matter why are you using the hidden input, its place is inside the `<form>` element, not on top of the script.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the reason the developer have done this, is because it is used in the first IF-statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['form_submitted'])):
```

When the form is submitted, it is sent to the same file. When a form is submitted, the form values is accessible via the `$_POST` paremeter in php. So if `$_POST['form_submitted']` is set, then he executes the following code, and if not, the code inside `else:` is executed

I also have to say that this code is not a good example of how to handle form submissions, and should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Developers using `<input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="">` because sometimes they use it as reference for the form submission. They can use it for conditions or whatever functionality they want to use with the `hidden` input.

Instead of showing the exact input (input text), they're hiding it for more cleaner form.